# Unable to use Xrm.Page.getControl to get an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, crm, xrm, dynamics-crm-2013

After the upgrade from dynamics-crm 2011 to dynamics-crm 2013 I am having some issues trying to refresh an iframe.

Previously and in the sdk Microsoft has to get a control/iframe use the "Xrm.Page.getControl()" or other posts say to use "Xrm.page.ui.controls.get()" below are the errors I am getting.[image]

I have found a work around but my concern is that it is not supported. I use Jquery to first retrieve the iframe that is the record since it is no longer its own window. Then I search for the Name/Id of my web-resource/iframe.

```
$("#contentIFrame0").contents().find("#WebResource_PowerTools")[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

This works and is what I am using now. My question is does any one know what happened to the `Xrm.Page.getControl()` or `Xrm.page.ui.controls`?

Answer (score 1):

In debugger there is a spelling mistake. It should be `Xrm.Page.ui.controls` instead of `Xrm.Page.ui.control`.

Below code should works for you.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("WebResource_PowerTools");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you try to reach and use XRM in iFrame. But Xrm functions are in window, so just do it like this :

```js
window.parent.Xrm.Page...
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.parent.Page.ui.controls.get("WebResource_PowerTools");`

Answer (score 0):

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('id_iframe').getObject().onload= function() {
    var element = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('id_iframe').getObject().contentWindow.document.getElementById('id_element_inside_iframe');
    console.log(element);
};
```

- Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('id_iframe').getObject():  Returns 
  the HTML object iFrame